# JSF2.0 Passing parameters to another Bean

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

When I send parameters within the action method to another page I can not read them from second Class.

page1.xhtml:

```
....
<h:commandLink action="#{mbean1.gotoMessageDetail(msg)}" value="#{msg.caption}"/>
....
```

Managed bean1

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbean1")
@RequestScoped
public class MBean1 {
 ....
 public String gotoMessageDetail(Message msg) {
    //do some work
    retrun "page2.xhtml?param1=val1&param2=val2";
  }
}
```

At the second class MBean2 I try to take parameters with the following code block but I cant get the parameters I sent.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbean2")
@ViewScoped
public class MBean2{
   ...
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  param1=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("param1")==null ? "0" : request.getParameter("param1"));
  param2=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("param2")==null ? "0" : request.getParameter("param2"));
}
```

The param1 and param2 come null.  How can I get param1 and param2 from mbean1's action method.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this typo `retrun`? Edit and try again.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbean1")
@RequestScoped
public class MBean1 {
 ....
 public String gotoMessageDetail(Message msg) {
    //do some work
    return "page2.xhtml?param1=val1&param2=val2";
    /////retrun to return
  }
}
```

For your information, you can use `@ManagedProperty` annotation to inject properties from one ManagedBean to another. Having the properties over at the other ManagedBean means you will not need to pass any parameters around.

Take a look at [Injecting Managed beans in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Zany.  But retrun is just the type error here. As I know @ManagedProperty works for sessionscoped beans.  but my beans are requestscopd and viewscoped.

Comment: @Mustafa: `@ManagedProperty` annotation injects any scoped bean as long as this managed property bean is of higher or equal scope than the managed bean.